# Omit image captions from get_the_content()

Tags: images, the-content, captions

I use a theme that calls `get_the_content()` to display short excerpts of the latest blog posts on the home page. Now I noticed that the excerpt sometimes starts with an image caption, if the blog post contains a picture at the very beginning. I usually do that and make the text float around it.

I always set the first three caption fields on an image (Alt Text, Title, Caption).

Is there any way to strip these image captions from the return value of `get_the_content()` or is there any other method that I could possibly call instead? I checked the documentation, but there seems no argument to exclude images from the return value.

Comment: have a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/strip_shortcodes/

Comment: it might be easier to add some CSS to hide img and/or caption tags in the targeted area.

Comment: `strip_tags()` and `strip_shortcodes()` are applied to the excerpt already, but the image caption is plain text. There is no CSS identifier either. Is there no alternative to `get_the_content()`?

Comment: "a theme that calls get_the_content() to display short excerpts of the latest blog posts" - please post the corresponding code

Comment: @Michael: Sure, just for you: `$output = get_the_content();`

Comment: what happens if you try to chnage that code section to: `$output = strip_shortcodes( get_the_content() );` ?

Comment: @Michael: `strip_shortcodes()` interfered with `strip_tags()` that was called prior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the method called `strip_tags(preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])", '', $output))` before `strip_shortcodes($output)`, which caused aforementioned issue, since the code removed shortcode in square brackets, but retained contained image captions.

I could fix it by swapping the two method calls like this:

```
$output = get_the_content();
$output = strip_shortcodes($output); // Strip WordPress shortcodes first!
$output = strip_tags(preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])", '', $output));
```